# image field “browse” button is not accessible

Tags: files

I have a strange problem with my web site. By add block I have an image field. 
The "browse" button is not acccessible for some people.

I can click on "browse" and choose a file but not an other role. For the other role the "browse" button does not appear.

Have you got an idea to fix this problem?